# Validação de Formulário com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ele mostra o erro somente em um campo por vez, ou seja a parte do "getElementById('tuser')" e o outro tpass, é o elemento do erro. Gostaria que se os dois estiverem nulos, mostre o erro nos dois de uma vez só. Porém, gostaria de utilizar esse mesmo método.

**Javascript:**

```
function validate(){

         if (document.formlog.usuario.value == ""){
            document.getElementById('tuser').style = "display:block;";
            return false;
         }

         if(document.formlog.senha.value == ""){
            document.getElementById('tpass').style = "display:block;";
            return false;
         }

         return true;
         loader();
}
```

**HTML (primeira parte do código)**

```
<form method="post" name="formlog" id="login-form" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return(validate());" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso evita dar retorno em cada um dos `if`. Podes começar a função "optimista" com `var valid = true;` e depois mudar para `false` caso um deles falhe.

Exemplo:

```js
function validate() {
  var valid = true;

  if (document.formlog.usuario.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('tuser').style = "display:block;";
    valid = false;
  }

  if (document.formlog.senha.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('tpass').style = "display:block;";
    valid = false;
  }

  return valid;
  loader(); // <----- isto nunca é usado (!) pois tens um return antes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer uma verificação dos 2 campos e retornar `false`.

Porém, para que a função `loader()` seja chamada após a validação positiva do formulário, é necessário retirar o `return true;` da função:

```
function validate(){

         if (document.formlog.usuario.value == "" && document.formlog.senha.value == ""){
            document.getElementById('tuser').style = "display:block;";
            document.getElementById('tpass').style = "display:block;";
            return false;
         }

         if (document.formlog.usuario.value == ""){
            document.getElementById('tuser').style = "display:block;";
            return false;
         }

         if(document.formlog.senha.value == ""){
            document.getElementById('tpass').style = "display:block;";
            return false;
         }

         loader();
}
```

```js
function validate(){

         if (document.formlog.usuario.value == "" && document.formlog.senha.value == ""){
            document.getElementById('tuser').style = "display:block;";
            document.getElementById('tpass').style = "display:block;";
            return false;
         }


         if (document.formlog.usuario.value == ""){
            document.getElementById('tuser').style = "display:block;";
            return false;
         }

         if(document.formlog.senha.value == ""){
            document.getElementById('tpass').style = "display:block;";
            return false;
         }

         loader();
}

function loader(){
 alert("Formulário enviado!");
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="formlog" id="login-form" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return(validate());" accept-charset="utf-8">
 <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" />
    <div id="tuser" style="display: none;">erro usuario</div>
    <br />
    <br />
 <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" />
    <div id="tpass" style="display: none;">erro senha</div>
    <br />
 <br />
 <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```